# MANTENER VALOR COLUMNA COMO TEXTO

Tags: script, app

Estoy creando mediante appsheet una app de inventario y tengo problemas con algunos de los códigos escaneados. Aunque el valor este configurado como texto sin formato, Google sheets los intenta calcular como formula y aparece un error de análisis de fórmula. Este es uno de los ejemplos: +DIVO6800291/$Z03B1N/16D20220314Z. La solución que he pensado para solucionar esto es crear un pequeño script para que todos los valores de la columna de los códigos de identificación de producto se mantengan como un formato texto. Soy nuevo con app script por lo que ando un poco perdido. Me podeis ayudar?Gracias